# template specialization c++ builder

Tags: c++, templates, c++builder

I create a class in c++ builder and this class have a function

```
static void foo(std::vector < bar* > x, int y);
```

but when I try to compile this code this error occur:

> `Undefined symbol 'bar'; Cannot generate template specialization from 'std::vector<_Ty, _Ax>'; >expected; ) expected;`

whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, there is no definition of the symbol `bar` available.

It needs to be delared at some point before the declaration of `foo`; either in the same file, or in a header included from it.

Comment: But `foo` was declared in header. All declarations are correct, this is my problem, if all declaration are correct why this error occur?

Comment: @adalrsjr1: Clearly, not all declarations are correct - there is no declaration of `bar` before `foo`. Where is `bar` declared, and how is that declaration included?

Comment: when I declare `foo(bar x)` its ok, but when I declare `foo(bar* x)` I have problem, how is possible?

Comment: @adalrsjr1: That shouldn't be possible, unless there's something very strange in your code. Where is `bar` declared, and how is that declaration included?

Comment: `bar` is declared in another .h file, and in the file where the `foo` is implemented I import the .h. I tested this code with g++ and run ok but in c++ builder occur this error, but I need develop this code with c++ builder

Comment: @adalrsjr1: The only possibilities I can think of are that you're not including the correct header file (perhaps there's another with the same name in the include path), or that it has include guards that clash with another header file (make sure the include guard doesn't begin with an underscore - for some reason, lots of people do that, even though it's not allowed and can cause problems). Otherwise, I'm afraid I can't help - your best approach is probably to somehow get the preprocessor output and see what's actually being included, but I've no idea how to do that in C++ builder.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that it does not know what `bar` is.  Where is `bar` defined?  If it has not been defined yet when the declaration of `foo()` is compiled, then you get the error.

Since you are using a pointer type for the template parameter, you can use a forward declaration for `bar` if you cannot fully define `bar` beforehand, eg:

```
class bar; // forward declaration
static void foo(std::vector < bar* > x, int y);
```

Comment: `bar` is defined in a header. I did as you show `class bar; static void foo(std::vector <bar*> x, int y);` now I can compile, but I can't acess the members of class `bar`

Comment: To access the members, you need to include `bar`'s header file in the source file that implements the body for `foo()`.